# Symfony5 : Override Mailer() parameters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, mailer

For one of my projects that I'm doing in symfony 5, I need to be able to send emails from different smtp accounts depending on the user.

The simple solution would be to create multiple entries in the .env file and then specify which one to use.
Unfortunately, the situation is different, and I would like to use informations from the db to "override" the info from the .env
But after a lot of research, I did not find any method allowing to "temporarily override" this information the time to carry out a sending.

The only method I had found was to generate a new Mailer() based on an EsmtpTransport() and send my mail that way.
Not optimal but functional.

When I tested to register a new user, i got a problem, the EmailVerifier() wants to use the informations from the .env
I decide to modify the EmailVerifier() to use my custom Mailer() but then another problem occurs, sending the mail by the EmailVerifier() shows an error:

> A message must have a text or an HTML part or attachments.

From:

```
(new TemplatedEmail())
                ...
                ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
```

Which is not a problem if I use the mailer generated in the __construct() but which crashes in my Mailer() ...

So I'm a little lost.
Is there a solution to override the parameters used by the Mailer()?
Is there an error in the code of the verification email?
Am I totally on the wrong method?

Thank you,
K

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?